# PHP Slideshow Won't Work on Internet Explorer

Tags: php, javascript, html, drupal, slideshow

I edited the slideshow on my Drupal site's landing page by accessing the PHP "page.tpl.php" directly and now the site won't work on IE8. It functions correctly on Mozilla and Chrome (by allowing for mouse over and links for the slideshow) but malfunctions with Internet Explorer. I only edited a small portion of the code to allow for basic HTML tags instead of just slideshow images. I changed this:

```
<div class="slideshow">
                <?php
                if($lang_name == "en"){
                ?>
                    <img src="<?php print $base_path . $directory; ?>/images/slideshows/ENGreplacementworkingoncomputer.png" width="950" height="355" alt="Legal Logik"/>
                    <img src="<?php print $base_path . $directory; ?>/images/slideshows/ENGreplacementhandshake.png" width="950" height="355" alt="Legal Logik"/>
                    <img src="<?php print $base_path . $directory; ?>/images/slideshows/ENGreplacementgirlstanding.png" width="950" height="355" alt="Legal Logik"/>
                <?php
                }else{
                ?>
                    <img src="<?php print $base_path . $directory; ?>/images/slideshows/FRreplacementworkingoncomputer.png" width="950" height="355" alt="Legal Logik"/>
                    <img src="<?php print $base_path . $directory; ?>/images/slideshows/FRreplacementhandshake.png" width="950" height="355" alt="Legal Logik"/>
                    <img src="<?php print $base_path . $directory; ?>/images/slideshows/FRreplacementgirlstanding.png" width="950" height="355" alt="Legal Logik"/>
                <?php
                }
                ?>
```

To this:

```
<div class="slideshow">
                <?php
                if($lang_name == "en"){
                ?>
                    <a href="https://www.legallogik.com/incorporation">
                    <img onmouseout="this.src='<?php print $base_path . $directory; ?>/images/slideshows/IncorporationENG1.png'" onmouseover="this.src='<?php print $base_path . $directory; ?>/images/slideshows/IncorporationENG2.png'" src="<?php print $base_path . $directory; ?>/images/slideshows/IncorporationENG1.png" width="950" height="355" alt="Legal Logik"/>
                    <a href="https://www.legallogik.com/business-transactions">
                    <img onmouseout="this.src='<?php print $base_path . $directory; ?>/images/slideshows/TransactionsENG1.png'" onmouseover="this.src='<?php print $base_path . $directory; ?>/images/slideshows/TransactionsENG2.png'" src="<?php print $base_path . $directory; ?>/images/slideshows/TransactionsENG1.png" width="950" height="355" alt="Legal Logik"/>
                    <a href="https://www.legallogik.com/services">
                    <img onmouseout="this.src='<?php print $base_path . $directory; ?>/images/slideshows/ServicesENG1.png'" onmouseover="this.src='<?php print $base_path . $directory; ?>/images/slideshows/ServicesENG2.png'" src="<?php print $base_path . $directory; ?>/images/slideshows/ServicesENG1.png" width="950" height="355" alt="Legal Logik"/>
                <?php
                }else{
                ?>
                    <a href="https://www.legallogik.com/fr/forfaits-dincorporation">
                    <img onmouseout="this.src='<?php print $base_path . $directory; ?>/images/slideshows/IncorporationFR1.png'" onmouseover="this.src='<?php print $base_path . $directory; ?>/images/slideshows/IncorporationFR2.png'" src="<?php print $base_path . $directory; ?>/images/slideshows/IncorporationFR1.png" width="950" height="355" alt="Legal Logik"/>
                    <a href="https://legallogik.com/fr/Transactions-Commerciales">
                    <img onmouseout="this.src='<?php print $base_path . $directory; ?>/images/slideshows/TransactionsFR1.png'" onmouseover="this.src='<?php print $base_path . $directory; ?>/images/slideshows/TransactionsFR2.png'" src="<?php print $base_path . $directory; ?>/images/slideshows/TransactionsFR1.png" width="950" height="355" alt="Legal Logik"/>
                    <a href="https://legallogik.com/fr/nos-services">
                    <img onmouseout="this.src='<?php print $base_path . $directory; ?>/images/slideshows/ServicesFR1.png'" onmouseover="this.src='<?php print $base_path . $directory; ?>/images/slideshows/ServicesFR2.png'" src="<?php print $base_path . $directory; ?>/images/slideshows/ServicesFR1.png" width="950" height="355" alt="Legal Logik"/>
                <?php
                }
                ?>
```

And left everything else the same. If anyone has any solutions or can point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated.

P.S. the ($lang_name =="en") is because the site has a translation module installed.

Comment: I don't think you're closing your <a> tags? It might also be useful to put up the end result in terms of HTML, the problem with IE will be the HTML and not the PHP (which is executed server side)

Comment: This is an issue strictly with the HTML and not with PHP. Look into your usage of quotes and single quotes and no ending anchor (`</a>`) tags on your `a href`s.

Comment: [Validate your html](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input) is probably a good suggestion (so the output of your website, not the php code building it). And seeing your js, I would suggest to look into a slightly smarter way of doing that, the only real change is the number 1 which changes to 2 in a mouseover.... sooo why not replace just that number with js which is not mixed in with the rest of the html? :-/ Or specify the alternate link in a data property and make the mouseover again in a separate js file.

Comment: First you should have a valid html document as sg3 suggests. then try again. i don't think that php has anything to do with the slideshow. If am right then this is an issue with the code executing on the client.

Answer (score 0):

I think this has to do with the HTML output of your PHP script, not the actual PHP itself.
Adding a semicollon might fix the problem.

```
<img onmouseout="this.src='<?php print $base_path . $directory;?>/images/slideshows/TransactionsFR1.png';"
```